# How to retrieve values from XML to C# wpf listview

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, listview

I've an XML like this:

```
<ConfData>
  <Person>
    <AgentInfo>
      <skillLevels>
        <SkillLevel>
          <skillDBID value="101" />
          <level value="10" />
        </SkillLevel>
        <SkillLevel>
          <skillDBID value="103" />
          <level value="10" />
        </SkillLevel>
        <SkillLevel>
          <skillDBID value="106" />
          <level value="10" />
        </SkillLevel>
        <SkillLevel>
          <skillDBID value="110" />
          <level value="10" />
        </SkillLevel>
        <SkillLevel>
          <skillDBID value="111" />
          <level value="10" />
        </SkillLevel>
        <SkillLevel>
          <skillDBID value="112" />
          <level value="10" />
        </SkillLevel>
        <CfgSkillLevel>
          <skillDBID value="113" />
          <level value="0" />
        </CfgSkillLevel>
      </skillLevels>
    </AgentInfo>
   </Person>
</ConfData>
```

And my .xaml code for the listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="AInfoLv">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn x:Name="LabelColumn" Header="Label" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Label}"/>
      <GridViewColumn x:Name="ValueColumn" Header="Value" Width="130" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

How can I retrieve all skillDBID values and level values and display them at the listview accordingly, which means the skillDBID values will be at Label column and level values will be at Value column?

Comment: have you researched this at all?  There are hundreds of examples out there...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you, to convert your xml file to an object in C#(Like Dictionary) and then bind your object with the xaml.

Answer (score 0):

To access an attribute in the XAML file, you need to use the @ symbol.

```
XPath=skillDBID/@value
```

This **XAML** works with your example XML file.

```
<Window.Resources>
  <XmlDataProvider Source='ConfData.xml'
                    x:Key='ConfXmlSource'
                    XPath="ConfData" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext='{Binding Source={StaticResource ConfXmlSource}}'>

  <ListView x:Name="AInfoLv"
            Grid.ColumnSpan='1'
            ItemsSource='{Binding XPath=/ConfData/Person/AgentInfo/skillLevels/SkillLevel}'>
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn x:Name="LabelColumn"
                        Header="Label"
                        Width="100"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=skillDBID/@value}" />
        <GridViewColumn x:Name="ValueColumn"
                        Header="Value"
                        Width="130"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=level/@value}" />
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
  </ListView>

</Grid>
```

Set the XMLDataProvider in code

```
 var provider = new XmlDataProvider();
 var xmlFile = new XmlDocument();
 xmlFile.Load(@"..\..\yourdoc.xml");
 provider.Document = xmlFile;
 provider.XPath = "/ConfData";

 AInfoLv.DataContext = provider;
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Walt Ritscher, thanks for your solution. May I know how can I pass XmlDataProvider source from the code to .xaml? Because I get my xml by going through certain process in the code.

Comment: I added an example of setting the XmlDataProvider.Document property in code.